# Convert date/time in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have the following date/time in the table that I need to convert and select anything that is less than 30 days.

I have two columns I have in a table: name, timestamp

timestamp is in this format: 2022-02-08T22:19:12:200

This is the query I tried so far just to select and convert the date to different format but getting oral-01843:not a valid month

select name, to_date(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from mytable;

Comment: You specify a format of `MM/DD/YYYY` but that doesn't match the format of the actual column.  You will need to create a date format string that matches the data you're trying convert.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: @AndyLester A `TIMESTAMP` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7-13 bytes and is never stored with any format (it is the client application used to read the data that choses to format timestamps in a particular format for the user and never the database). The OP's problem is that they are using `TO_DATE` when they should be using either `TO_CHAR` (if they want to format the timestamp) or `TRUNC` (if they want to convert to a `DATE` data type with the time component at midnight).

Comment: I understand, but I don't think OP's dealing with a `TIMESTAMP`. It seems to me that OP's column "timestamp" is actually VARCHAR2.

Comment: Correct my column timestamp is 'VARCHAR2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `timestamp` column is soted in a `TIMESTAMP` data type then you do not need to convert the column to a different format (firstly, because a `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-13 bytes representing 7 bytes for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and then 6 optional bytes for fractional seconds and is not stored in any human-readable format; and secondly, because conversion is not necessary as you can do it without).

To find the rows that are less than exactly 30 days old, you can use:

```sql
SELECT name, timestamp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp >= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY;
```

If you want to ignore the time component then you can use:

```sql
SELECT name, timestamp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '30' DAY;
```

If you want to **display** the timestamp column in a format (rather than comparing two dates/times) then you can use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT name,
       TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS formatted_timestamp
FROM   table_name
```

---

If your column is a `VARCHAR2` data type and you are storing the string in ISO8601 format then you can use:

```sql
SELECT name, timestamp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp >= TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

Or, if you want to ignore the time component, then just remove the time component from the format model in `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT name, timestamp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp >= TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you want to **display** your string in a different format then convert it to a timestamp and then back to a string:

```sql
SELECT name,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
         'MM/DD/YYYY'
       ) AS formatted_date
FROM   table_name
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=075098994a3d9ac42d8be657e3ac9ff7)*

Comment: Sorry but to just display timestamp is not working, I'm getting ora-01722: invalid number. Also, two queries to display 30 days old don't work either.

Comment: @R_sol That is because you are using a string to store a timestamp and not following best practice and using a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type. I've updated the answer for ISO8601 formatted strings.

Comment: This worked, thank you!